# Rails 3: How to get image path in Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

To get the image path in Controller I use the following method:

```
class AssetsController < ApplicationController
  def download(image_file_name)
    path = Rails.root.join("public", "images", image_file_name).to_s
    send_file(path, ...)
  end
end
```

Is there a better method to find the path ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Asset Path from Rails Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827078/access-asset-path-from-rails-controller)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('missing_file.jpg')
```

[Access Asset Path from Rails Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827078/access-asset-path-from-rails-controller)

Comment: This did not work for me, I wanted to use `image_path` not `asset_path`. It could not target files in my images folder. Using `view_context` worked instead.

Comment: For anybody using webpacker to handle static assets use this instead: `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_pack_path('missing_file.jpg')`.

Answer (score 24):

Not sure if this was added as early as Rails 3, but is definitely working in Rails 3.1.  You can now access the `view_context` from your controller, which allows you to call methods that are normally accessible to your views:

```
class AssetsController < ApplicationController
  def download(image_file_name)
    path = view_context.image_path(image_file_name)
    # ... use path here ...
  end
end
```

Note that this will give you the publicly accessible path (e.g.: "/assets/foobar.gif"), not the local filesystem path.

Comment: Worked for me in Rails 4

Comment: Worked for me in Rails 4, including `asset_url` which doesn't add domain in `ActionController::Base.helpers`.

Comment: This does not work when there is no view_context. In that case, prefer deefour's solution

Answer (score 8):

`view_context.image_path('noimage.jpg')`

Comment: A little explanation would be nice!

Comment: <pre>
class SomeControllerController < ApplicationController
    def some_method
      view_context.image_path('noimage.jpg')
    end
  end
</pre>

Comment: I believe view_context loads asset_path and image_path as dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

Asset url:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path(my_path)
```

Image url:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path(my_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

`view_context` works for me in Rails 4.2 and Rails 5.

Find some codes in Rails repo explains `view_context`:

```
# definition
module ActionView
  # ...
  module Rendering
    # ...
    def view_context
      view_context_class.new(view_renderer, view_assigns, self)
    end
  end
end

# called in controller module
module ActionController
  # ...
  module Helpers
    # Provides a proxy to access helper methods from outside the view.
    def helpers
      @_helper_proxy ||= view_context
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -3):

You might want to check out `image_path(image.png)` for your scenario.

Here are the examples from [the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/image_path):

```
image_path("edit")                                 # => "/images/edit"
image_path("edit.png")                             # => "/images/edit.png"
image_path("icons/edit.png")                       # => "/images/icons/edit.png"
image_path("/icons/edit.png")                      # => "/icons/edit.png"
image_path("http://www.example.com/img/edit.png")  # => "http://www.example.com/img/edit.png"
```