# Access Asset Path from Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets

I'm sharing a configuration yml file client side, that I need to also load on the server side, I've placed it inside app/assets/javascripts/configuration.yml

I can use #{asset_path 'configuration.yml'} inside a view to get the path, but I can't inside a controller. I could access directly using "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/javascripts/configuration.yml" but when deploying the filename gets the digest string appended.

How can I get the same path from a controller?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("configuration.yml")
```

Might also be good to put configuration.yml in a different folder to separate javascript from non-javascript files.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't need to use `/assets/`. I can just call ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("configuration.yml")

I also thought about putting the yml file on another folder, tried adding it directly to the app/assets folder, but I couldn't access it. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: @MarcelM. you need to add other folder to the search path in application.rb. Like so `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "yml")`

Comment: This is deprecated in Rails 4.

Comment: @Agis — perhaps include the new recommended solution.