# Asset Pipeline in Active Model Serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, active-model-serializers

I'm attempting to include an image asset pipeline url in my model serializer output by including ActiveView::Helpers:

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  include ActiveView::Helpers

  attributes :post_image

  def post_image
    image_path "posts/#{object.id}"
  end
end
```

The result is `/images/posts/{id}` rather than a valid path to the asset pipeline path, ie. `/assets/images/posts/{id}`. How can I include valid asset pipeline paths in my serializer output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access Asset Path from Rails Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827078/access-asset-path-from-rails-controller)

Answer (score 9):

Maybe this could work:

```
def post_image
  _helpers = ActionController::Base.helpers
  _helpers.image_url "posts/#{object.id}"
end
```

Answer (score 6):

(Very) late to the party, but you can solve the problem by adding this to your `ApplicationController` :

```
serialization_scope :view_context
```

and then in the serializer :

```
def post_image
  scope.image_url('my-image.png')
end
```

**Explanation :** When your controller instanciates a serializer, it passes a `scope` (context) object along (by default, the controller itself I think). Passing the `view_context` allows you to use any helper that you would be able to use in a view.

Answer (score 2):

So I have been struggling with this for a little bit today. I found a slightly less then ideal solution. The `ActionController::Base.helpers` solution didn't work for me.

This is certainly not the most optimal solution. My thinking is that the proper solution might be to add a 'set_configs' initializer to ActiveModelSerializer.

The `ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper` utilizes a function called `compute_asset_host` which reads `config.asset_host`. This property looks to be set in railtie initializers for ActionViews and ActionControllers. [ActionController::RailTie](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb#L31)

So I ended up subclassing the ActiveModel::Serializer and setting the `config.asset_host` property in the constructor, like so.

```
class BaseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  include ActiveSupport::Configurable
  include AbstractController::AssetPaths
  include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper

  def initialize(object, options={})
    config.asset_host = YourApp::Application.config.action_controller.asset_host

    super
  end
end
```

This got me most of the way. These helpers methods also use a protocol value; it can be passed in as a param in an options hash, a config variable, or read from the request variable. so I added a helper method in my `BaseSerializer` to pass the correct options along.

```
def image_url(path)
  path_to_asset(path, {:type=>:image, :protocol=>:https})
end
```