# Rails 4: undefined method `asset_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use `asset_path` in my controller to generate the path for a  pdf that is placed in my `assets/data/` directory. Is this obsolete in Rails 4?

Here is my controller code that throws the error:

```
  def beg_1
    File.open(asset_path("ee-beg-1.pdf"), 'r') do |f|
      send_data f.read.force_encoding('BINARY'), :filename => "ee-beg-1.pdf", :type => "application/pdf"
    end
  end
```

Comment: maybe it needs to be wrapped in a string like this? `"#{asset_path('ee-beg-1.pdf')}"`

Comment: @NielsB. you are right, asset_path returns a string, which is what File.open() takes for the `filename` param: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/File.html#method-c-open

Comment: Change to `File.open('app/assets/data/ee-beg-1.pdf')`

Comment: Ça marche! Do you happen to know how instead of downloading the PDF how it can be viewed in the browser? Sorry this is a different question, so I understand if you have no desire to answer that here.

Comment: On a side note, I would strongly advise against serving downloadable content for your site/app in the assets directory.  Assets directory has a special purpose in Rails applications, it is not just a file store.  I would recommend serving downloads from a sub-directory inside lib.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`asset_path` is a view helper. It is not obsolete in Rails 4.

See [#asset_path](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path) at http://api.rubyonrails.org.

This similar Question and Answer should provide a solution for you:

[Access Asset Path from Rails Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827078/access-asset-path-from-rails-controller)