# How to use image_url in rails to show images in production?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, url

I have this code

```
<div class="w-col w-col-7 w-col-stack w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny col-spc">
     <div class="nivo-slice" style="left: 0px; width: 900px; height: 100%; opacity: 1;">
          <img src="/assets/home/toppho08.jpg" alt="toppho08.jpg">
     </div>

</div>
```

and it work well in development but when i tried to run it in production, images won't be displayed. So, I was told to use image_url but it html seems to not accept the code. I have this instead and it went okay.

```
<img src="http://sitename.com/assets/home/toppho08.jpg" alt="toppho08.jpg">
```

But I want to use the image_url.
How do I apply `image_url` in html?

These links do not answer my question
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html
http://awardwinningfjords.com/2009/05/11/simplify-image-paths-with-image_url.html
https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/54731/#268424
[Rails 4 not right path for image_url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630074/rails-4-not-right-path-for-image-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this it will work for you:

```
<%= image_tag 'home/toppho08.jpg' %>
```

or

```
<%= image_tag image_url('home/toppho08.jpg') %>
```

Comment: thanks, it works...can you help me with css matter?

.photo-client._4 {
  background-image: image-tag('home/client4.jpg');
}

this won't work.. the image won't show.. i have this under my html by the way <div class="photo-client _4">

Comment: use image-url in place of image-tag

Comment: background-image: image-url("home/client4.jpg"); <---- i did this already but still didn't work

Comment: If your css file is with the '.css' extension then this should be work : background-image: url("/assets/home/client4.jpg")

Comment: So in that case try to use 'asset-data-url', please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257555/how-to-reference-images-in-css-within-rails-4#

Comment: i tried again the image_url, it did work.. i just forgot to run this again after changing to image_url ---> rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production. Thanks a lot, it's a great help for me.. please accept the votes on your comments as my thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Following is enough to use `image_tag`

```
<%= image_url 'home/toppho08.jpg' %>
```

Comment: it didn't work.. this is displayed instead of the photo >>> http://localhost:3000/assets/home/toppho08-99a5359e9ccec442303bd25ffbabd45f.jpg

Comment: May be it is a assets precompiling issue, try `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: rake assets:precompile is already done and under production.rb, i alread set the config.serve_static_assets to true as well as the digest. what else could it be?

Comment: It must have to work. Now its not look like a `tag` issue. Its some production server configuration issue. Which production server you are using ?

Comment: as of now, i tried to run it in localhost production just to test if it's going to work on server

Comment: Add `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production` in your Gemfile, if you are using `Heroku`

Comment: if this counts as server, i am using a personal name from the client... www.clientsbusinessname.com. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help.. image_tag worked. please accept my vote up to your answer for helping me. :)