# Rails 4.2 image_path with different url for controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm using image_path into my controller:

```
class ArchivesController < ApplicationController
    include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper

    def create
        @archive = Archive.new(file: params[:file])

        render json: {ico: image_path('docs/pdf.png')}
    end
end
```

But my return is `{ico: '/images/docs/pdf.png'}`.

When I'm use `image_path('docs/pdf.png')` in my views, the url is '/docs/pdf.png' and works.

Why in my controller the url is different?

Comment: What happens when you prepend a slash like this **'/docs/pdf.png'** in controller

Comment: I'm not sure why they're different but you could use `view_context.image_path 'pdf.png'` without including the helper library.

Comment: Thanks @mmichael!! With view_context.image_path worked. I didn't know I could use the view_context. Very, Very Thanks.

Comment: I believe you're in need of "ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path(fileHere)  .  Checkout this post for more info:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827078/access-asset-path-from-rails-controller

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer from my comment:

You can use `view_context.image_path 'pdf.png'` without including the helper library.